# How to convert a python object to string with non-ascii character unchanged?

Tags: python, string

I have an object like:

```
obj1 = {
    'k1' : 'v1', 
    'k2' : [
        {
            'k21' : '中文字符'
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert it to a string like :

```
'''{ 'k1' : 'v1', 'k2' : [ { 'k21' : '中文字符' } ] } '''
```

using str() give me this:

```
'''{'k2': [{'k21': '\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87\xe5\xad\x97\xe7\xac\xa6'}], 'k1': 'v1'}'''
```

Notice that '\xe4' has four chars. I guess that str() simply calls repr().

One solution is traveling all the key of the object and recursively handle it. I am wondering is there any other way to achieve it. Such as converting the '\xe4' to '中' or directly convert obj1 to the excepted result.

Thanks!

Comment: The step of converting from the dictionary to the JSON string can easily be done using the [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: that's required so your javascript structure can be represented as json. You're embedding unicode chars, which MUST use multiple bytes for "foreign" characters.

Comment: Python 3 handles this fine, are you using 2.x?

Comment: @JasonS yes, I am using 2.7.5. Do you mean str() in python 3 outputs what I want?

Comment: @Cyber json.dumps() produce '''{"k2": [{"k21": "\u4e2d\u6587\u5b57\u7b26"}], "k1": "v1"}'''

Comment: @MarcB I have declared utf-8 in the first line of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what @Cyber suggested, using `json` will be an option, like this:

```
import json

In [11]: obj1 = {
    ...:     'k1' : 'v1', 
    ...:     'k2' : [
    ...:         {
    ...:             'k21' : '中文字符'
    ...:         }
    ...:     ]
    ...: }
         # remember to set ensure_ascii=False
In [12]: s = json.dumps(obj1, ensure_ascii=False)

In [13]: print s
{"k2": [{"k21": "中文字符"}], "k1": "v1"}
```

I'm on **Python 2.7.8**